# Что произойдет с текстом после replaceAll("//","/0/") ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Я понимаю, что все, что подходит под `"//"`, заменится на `"/0/"`. Но что означают `"//"` и `"/0/"`?

```
for (int i = 1;i < coordstext.length;i++) {
    String fixstring = coordstext[i].replaceAll("//","/0/");
    String[] tempstring = fixstring.split("/");
    v[i-1] = Integer.valueOf(tempstring[0]).intValue();
    if (tempstring.length > 1) {
        vt[i-1] = Integer.valueOf(tempstring[1]).intValue();
    } else {
        vt[i-1] = 0;
    }
    if (tempstring.length > 2) {
        vn[i-1] = Integer.valueOf(tempstring[2]).intValue();
    } else {
        vn[i-1] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы это встретили в чужом коде? Если да, может поделитесь фрагментом, где встречается это выражение?

Comment: @Dazar добавил. Это фрагмент алгоритма чтения obj файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае `"//"`, `"/0/"` это просто текст. В строке

```
String fixstring = coordstext[i].replaceAll("//","/0/");
```

Происходит замена `//` на `/0/`, например, если был текст

```
"word//word//word"
```

То в результате бы получилось

```
"word/0/word/0/word"
```

Далее из строки

```
String[] tempstring = fixstring.split("/");
```

Видно, что текст разделяется по массивам, будет, например, вот так

```
tempstring[0] = "word"
tempstring[1] = "0"
tempstring[2] = "word"
tempstring[3] = "0"
tempstring[4] = "word"
```

Далее уже идут какие-то преобразования (не смотрел)